# Laravel5.2 schedule:run don't work with cron job

Tags: php, cron, laravel-5

I'm having a problem with the php artisan schedule:run. I have the following cron job on GoDaddy :

```
/usr/bin/php /home/usr/framework/artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1
```

Every time, I got this error message:

```
local.ERROR: exception 'ErrorException' with message 'Invalid argument supplied for foreach()' in /home/usr/framework/vendor/symfony/console/Input/ArgvInput.php:286
Stack trace:
#0 /home/usr/framework/vendor/symfony/console/Input/ArgvInput.php(286): Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\HandleExceptions->handleError(2, 'Invalid argumen...', '/home/usr...', 286, Array)
#1 /home/usr/framework/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(740): Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput->hasParameterOption(Array, true)
#2 /home/usr/framework/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(114): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->configureIO(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#3 /home/usr/framework/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/Kernel.php(107): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#4 /home/usr/framework/artisan(35): Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel->handle(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#5 {main}
```

But if I go in the terminal and write this:

```
php artisan schedule:run
```

All work fine. I really don't know where I should look to solve this. I need your help to solve this. Thank you.

Comment: Disclaimer: I have zero experience with GoDaddy but after searching a bit I found that they have some kind of notification system for cron jobs, this might mean they do something strange with the ending of your cron job (`>> /dev/null 2>&1`) which simply discards the result. Try removing that part and see if it runs then.

Comment: Hi! 

Did you get any solution. I just face the same problem. Can you help me?

Comment: Long time I did not connect, do you still have the problem?

Answer (score 2):

For me, in the cron job, I changed 'php' to 'php-cli -q' and it now works.

So:

```
* * * * * php-cli -q /home/user/laravel/artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1
```

Answer (score 2):

Change your cron job to the following:

```
* * * * * /usr/local/bin/php /home/user/laravel/artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1
```

I believe it's your PHP path that's incorrect.

Comment: This works. specifically the `/usr/local/bin/php` was what sorted my jobs out. Thanks!